# Stroustrup reason for using auto when defining a variable

Tags: c++, c++11

I am reading Bjarne Stroustrup "The C++ programming language" book, and it is mentioned that one of the reasons for using **auto** in a variable definition is:

> The definition is in a large scope where we want to make the type clearly visible to readers of our code.

What is the meaning of large scope here? and anyone has an example for this statement, as I feel it is not clear how using auto is making the type clearly visible to readers of the code.

Comment: I think that is supposed to be a reason _not_ to use `auto`. Sentence prior: "_We use auto where we don’t have a specific reason to mention the type explicitly. ‘‘Specific
reasons’’ include:_". "_specific reasons_" refers to reasons to mention the type explicit and therefore _not_ use `auto`.

Comment: @OP I think you should read carefully the prior sentence. As pointed out by `user17732522`, the author is giving some "specific reasons" to use `auto`.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo as this seems to be a misunderstanding of OP and this question won't help future readers which can read the prior sentence before asking this question. You should also include whole paragraph in your question instead of just cherry picking and quoting a sentence out of context.

Comment: Thanks, I misinterpreted the sentence

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You took only part of the quote from the book. The entire quote is:

> We use auto where we **don’t** have a specific reason to mention the type
> explicitly. ‘‘Specific reasons’’ include:
>
> - The definition is in a large scope where we want to make the type clearly visible to readers of our code.
> - We want to be explicit about a variable’s range or precision (e.g., double rather than float).

The part you mentioned in the question is the *Specific reason* when `auto` should **not** be used, so exactly the opposite you thought.

I.e., when you want to make the type clearly visible to readers, you should not use `auto`.